# How can I customize the colors used for reStructuredText?

Tags: colors

Somehow I got into the situation where my section headings in ReST mode are rendered in one shade of gray for the foreground and another, nearly identical shade of gray for the background.  This makes the section headings almost completely unreadable to me.

So, I am a simple user with a rather simple question: How can I customize the colors for ReST mode to fix this?

Here is the output of my `version` command:

```
GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.21) of 2013-10-25 on allspice, modified by Debian
```

Comment: This is very much related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13752/115.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the cursor on one of those section headings, and hit `C-u C-x =`. Emacs will tell you, near the bottom of buffer `*Help*`, what face(s) is/are used for the highlighting.

Then use `M-x customize-face` to specify each face (there might be only one that you need to change), and then tweak the definition as you like. Use the action menu to set your changes for the current session or save them also for future sessions.

Comment: An old answer but still works like a charm. `C-u C-x =` gives the definition and also lists how to change the properties of that rule